# swprintf unexpected results

Tags: c++, c

I am trying to use [RtlStringCbPrintfW](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff562824%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) (safe version of swprintf), and got unexpected results when appending int to string.
 If i append the same string after int - all works. So my code:

```
WCHAR buffer[256];

    LPCWSTR pszFormat = L"%s %d";

    WCHAR* pszTxt = dataPath.Buffer;//*

    status = RtlStringCbPrintfW(buffer, sizeof(buffer), pszFormat, pszTxt, 1);
```

- Here dataPath is [UNICODE_STRING](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa380518%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). So dataPath.Buffer is PWCH
  Here a see that buffer value is: buffer = wchar_t [168] "\Device\HarddiskVolume2\foo\Data??C???"

When watch buffer array i can see that '?' are:

```
0xcc00 '?'
0xcccc '?'
```

then after some bytes is actually target value 1 is located. 
 The value of dataPath.Buffer:

```
   +0x048 DataPath         : _UNICODE_STRING "\Device\HarddiskVolume2\foo\Data"
      +0x000 Length           : 0x8c
      +0x002 MaximumLength    : 0x8c
      +0x008 Buffer           : 0xffffc000`01cd1d00  "\Device\HarddiskVolume2\foo\Data"
```

So what is the reson, null terminated char? Shouldn't be automaticly handled correctly with swprintf?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
%wZ
```

[Type Field Character](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/hf4y5e3w.aspx) should be used for UNICODE_STRING structure.

Answer (score 2):

The documentation for `UNICODE_STRING` that you link to states that `Buffer` is not necessarily null-terminated and the `%s` format requires a null-terminated string.

You can restrict the length of a string printed with `%s` by specifying a precision:

```
WCHAR* pszTxt = dataPath.Buffer;
int Len = dataPath.Length;

RtlStringCbPrintfW(buffer, sizeof(buffer), L"%.*s %d", Len, pszTxt, 1);
```

Comment: And why this one not works? RtlStringCbPrintfW(buffer,
   sizeof(buffer),
   L"%.*s%s", 
   dataPath.Length,
   dataPath.Buffer,
   L"\\"); ..L"\\" is null terminated

Comment: What doesn't wprk? What value of `buffer` do you get?

Comment: Like "\Device\HarddiskVolume2\foo\Data??C???" . I found correct answer there is spetial parametr %wZ for UNICODE_STRING, it works, so solved

Comment: Okay, so using `%wZ` is the actual answer to your question. Sorry for the misdirection.